# Is this function doing something wrong with the sockets?

Tags: c++, sockets, winsock2

I am using the following function to receive XML files for a while, but it has been going wrong for some time now and I think the problem is on the customer's network. I'm not sure, it's just a guess.
It happens some times when they try to send me XMLs files bigger than 13KB - the received buffer contains trash like this:

```
...
    <Identifiers>
      <Identifier>
        <PID>E3744</PID>
      </Identifier>
      <Identifier IDType="SHC">
        <PID>10021020</PID>
      </Identifier>
      <Identifier><*X| Å  Å    Ÿòc PV“R¢ E ·Â÷@ @€ˆ
þõ
øæ=Ì×KåÅôdËÞ¦P s÷j  
        <PID>1002102-0</PID>
      </Identifier>
      <Identifier>
        <PID>1002102</PID>
      </Identifier>
    </Identifiers>
...
```

Here is the fuction:

```
bool ReceiveBuffer(HWND hDlg, const SOCKET& socket, string& sBuffer)
{
    WSAAsyncSelect(socket, hDlg, WM_WINSOCK, FD_CLOSE);
    int iBufSize = 10000000; //10MB
    int iBufVarSize = sizeof(iBufSize);

    if (setsockopt(socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF, (char*)&iBufSize, iBufVarSize) == SOCKET_ERROR)
        if (getsockopt(socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF, (char*)&iBufSize, &iBufVarSize) == SOCKET_ERROR)
            WriteLog("Unable to GET buffer receiving size");

    char* buf = (char*)MALLOCZ(iBufSize);

    if (!buf)
    {
        WriteLog("Unable to allocate memory"); 
        return false;
    }

    int iCharsRead = 0;

    do
    {
        memset(buf, 0, iBufSize);
        iCharsRead = recv(socket, buf, iBufSize, 0);

        if (iCharsRead > 0)
            sBuffer.append(buf, iCharsRead);
    }
    while (iCharsRead > 0);

    FREE(buf);
    buf = NULL;

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`ReceiveBuffer()` should not be calling `WSAAsyncSelect()` or setting `SO_RCVBUF`.  That is the responsibility of whatever code initially creates the `SOCKET`.

But more importantly, `WSAAsyncSelect()` puts the socket into non-blocking mode, per the documentation:

> The `WSAAsyncSelect` function automatically sets socket `s` to nonblocking mode, regardless of the value of `lEvent`.

However, your reading loop is not accounting for possible `WSAEWOULDBLOCK` errors from `recv()` so it can call `recv()` again to keep reading.

`ReceiveBuffer()` is also *assuming* that if `setsockopt()` succeeds then the actual buffer size is really the requested size, which is not guaranteed.  So you need to call `getsockopt()` regardless of whether `setsockopt()` succeeds or fails, per the documentation:

> SO_RCVBUF and SO_SNDBUF
>   When a Windows Sockets implementation supports the `SO_RCVBUF` and `SO_SNDBUF` options, an application can request different buffer sizes (larger or smaller). **The call to `setsockopt` can succeed even when the implementation did not provide the whole amount requested. An application must call `getsockopt` with the same option to check the buffer size actually provided.**

But really, setting `SO_RCVBUF` on every call to `ReceiveBuffer()` is not necessary in the first place.  `recv()` returns whatever data is currently available at that moment, up to the requested buffer size.  It is very unlikely that it will return anywhere close to 10MB of data on any given read.  So you are just wasting a lot of memory for no real benefit.  It is one thing to set the *socket's* internal buffer to 10MB if you are on a fast network.  It is another thing to allocate a *memory* buffer of 10MB to receive data from each `recv()` call.  You should use a much smaller memory buffer.  1K is a common size to use.

But beyond that, regardless of the buffer size you use, `ReceiveBuffer()` is reading arbitrary bytes in an endless loop until the socket is disconnected or errors (and not accounting for non-blocking errors).  When the socket does eventually disconnect/error, `ReceiveBuffer()` is returning true instead of false, so the caller has no idea that something went wrong, or that `sBuffer` may be incomplete.

Also, in case the caller calls `ReceiveBuffer()` multiple times with the same variable for the `sBuffer` parameter, you should call `sBuffer.clear()` before starting the reading loop to make sure you are not appending new data to the end of stale data.

Now, all of the above is just technical issues with your code logic.  But there is also a semantic element as well.  XML has a finite length to it, but your current code has no way of knowing what that length actually is.  It is the sender's responsibility to tell the receiver when the XML has stopped being sent.  That could be by sending the XML's length before sending the XML itself, so the receiver knows how many bytes to expect.  Or that could be by sending a unique delimiter, like a null terminator, at the end of the XML, so the receiver can stop reading when it sees the delimiter.  Or that could be by gracefully closing the connection at the end of the XML (which is a bad idea, because then the receiver can't differentiate between end-of-data and data loss).  But it has to do something.

Now, with all of that said, try something more like this instead (I'm assuming a graceful disconnect is the end-of-data indicator, since that is what your original code is doing - you need to seriously consider a different protocol design!):

```
bool ReceiveBuffer(SOCKET socket, string& sBuffer)
{
    sBuffer.clear();

    /*
    int iBufSize = 1024 * 1024 * 10; //10MB
    setsockopt(socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF, (char*)&iBufSize, sizeof(iBufSize));
    if (getsockopt(socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF, (char*)&iBufSize, sizeof(iBufSize)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
        WriteLog("Unable to GET buffer receiving size");
    */

    char* buf = (char*) malloc(1024);
    if (!buf)
    {
        WriteLog("Unable to allocate memory"); 
        return false;
    }

    int iCharsRead;
    bool bRet = true;

    do
    {
        iCharsRead = recv(socket, buf, 1024, 0);
        if (iCharsRead > 0)
        {
            sBuffer.append(buf, iCharsRead);
        }
        else if (iCharsRead == 0)
        {
            // socket disconnected gracefully
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            if (WSAGetLastError() != WSAEWOULDBLOCK)
            {
                // socket error!
                WriteLog("Unable to read from socket"); 
                bRet = false;
                break;
            }

            // socket is non-blocking and there is no data available
            // at this moment.  Call recv() again...

            // optional: call select() to wait for new data to arrive
            // before calling recv() again.  For instance, this will
            // allow you to fail the function if no new data arrived
            // within a timeout period...
            //
            /*
            fd_set fd;
            FD_ZERO(&fd);
            FD_SET(socket, &fd);

            timeval tv;
            tv.tv_sec = 30;
            tv.tv_usec = 0;

            int ret = select(0, &fd, NULL, NULL, &tv);
            if (ret <= 0)
            {
                if (ret == 0)
                {
                    // timeout!
                    WriteLog("Timeout waiting for data from socket"); 
                }
                else
                {
                    // socket error!
                    WriteLog("Unable to wait for data from socket"); 
                }
                bRet = false;
                break;
            }
            */
        }
    }
    while (true);

    free(buf);

    return bRet;
}
```